# Dynamic IP Blocking on FORTIGATE 200A Firewall

Tags: firewall, ip-blocking, fortinet, fortigate

I have FORTIGATE 200A firewall protecting a IIS Server running a ASP.NET website (windows server 2008 and IIS7)

I'm not familiar with Fortigate configurations and options.

I recently had "attacks" from certain IPs that generate a lot of errors by submitting different forms with invalid parameters to the website.

I'd like to be able to block a list of IP addresses for 24hrs based on a list generated from the asp.net code (text file).

**Any idea how to update the fortigate 200A firewall with this list of temporary blocked IP's?
Maybe via batch file ?**

Comment: Many providers offer an API which allows you to interact programmatically with their products. For instance http://bit.ly/1yxcEbn